# Field editable based Approval Process

Tags: approval-process

The requirement is when once user submit for approval, all the field in the layout become read only except for certain field.But once the request is rejected,all the field become editable.Currently I am using Read Only setting in Page Layout.But it disable all field 'forever'.For this case, is there any configuration to do it or I need to control it using code.

Answer (score 2):

With approval processes, when a record is submitted for approval the record is locked.
So you can't define fields that are still editable and fields that are not, all the fields become read-only, except for few users.
This is documented here:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=approvals_considerations.htm&language=en_US

> Records are locked while in an approval process. The ability to edit a locked record depends on the record editability setting of the approval process:
>   Administrators ONLY: Only users with the “Modify All” object-level permission for the given object, or the “Modify All Data” permission, can edit locked records.
>   Administrators or the currently assigned approver...: The current approver and users who match the Administrators ONLY criteria can edit locked records. The current approver must also have edit access to the record through their permissions and the organization-wide sharing defaults for the given object.

Answer (score 1):

You could use two record types, each with their own layout, and then let field-update actions in the approval process control which record type/page layout is set for that record.

Abdel-Ali B. makes a good point that while the record is submitted for approval, only the admin and approver (if the approval process was set up that way) would be able to edit the record. Using additional record types and page layouts could still help you control access to certain fields, but the limitations due to the lock on pending approvals still apply.